# TFS Reporting, select query to retrieve source code repository metadata

Tags: tfs

I would like to create a report from our TFS database which selects all source code repository names and commit history for these repositories. We are using git and it is integrated with TFS, but I am not sure how to access commit history from the TFS database.

I'd like to create something like this

```
Repository 1 - Name
Commit 1- author - date
Commit 2- author - date
Commit 3- author - date
Repository 2 - Name
Commit 1- author - date
Commit 2- author - date
Commit 3- author - date
```

I was reading this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/table-reference-relational-warehouse-database?view=azure-devops-2019#SourceCode

Though that's not quite what I want, it got me started. Looking at the schema I found these tables:

DimChangeset (changeset data)
DimFile (individual files changed)
DimPerson (user data)
DimTeamProject (Teams project)

That seems to cover most of what I need, however I am not seeing where to get the repository names that are within the teams projects. Any suggestions? The repository names are in the TFS UI, so I assume they are stored in the database somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL data warehouse and analysis cubes are deprecated. They haven't received updates for new features for many, many years -- that includes Git repos and JSON/YAML build/releases. What you're seeing is for TFVC repos, not Git repos.

The modern implementation is the [OData analytics feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/?view=azure-devops). However, it's not available in versions prior to Azure DevOps Server 2019. Unfortunately, repos aren't yet supported. There's not really a supported way to get the information you're after right now. You can query repo information using the REST APIs, but it's not in a format that's really intended to be used for tracking trends.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this information! Our company is actually planning to migrate to Azure DevOps Server 2019 next month, so perhaps I will wait until then to take a look at this. I took a look at the REST API documentation to get the repo information, seems like I could ingest this into PowerBI with a custom PowerQuery connector. Anyway, will hold off for now, thanks again